# python loop not adding 1

Tags: python

No matter what I try, "i" always stays as "1". I am trying a add "1" to "i" each time it goes to the next file containing "1Chr" in the folder.

python

```
for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
  i = 1
  with open(name) as k:
    content = k.read()
    if '1Chr.'+str(i)+'.' in name:
      book = name.split('.')[0].upper().rstrip()
      x=open('final/'+book+'.SFM', 'a')
      x.write(content)
      i += 1
      x.close()
```

Comment: You are resetting `i` to `1` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: you set i=1 at the begining of each iteration. Probably you want to set i=1 before the for statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the `i = 1` above your for loop.
For every new file, you are resetting `i` to be one, so it can't go beyond 2.

Answer (score 4):

place the `i=1` above the for loop:

```
i = 1
for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
  with open(name) as k:
    content = k.read()
    if '1Chr.'+str(i)+'.' in name:
      book = name.split('.')[0].upper().rstrip()
      x=open('final/'+book+'.SFM', 'a')
      x.write(content)
      i += 1
      x.close()
```

or better use `enumerate()`, `enumerate()` will automatically increment `i`:

```
for i,name in enumerate(glob.glob('*.html'),1):
```

Comment: I like the `enumerate` suggestion but it would need a bit of tweaking to the code here, because the OP isn't counting each `html` file but only those where `'1Chr.'+str(i)+'.' in name` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Put `i=1` outside the `for` loop.  You're resetting it to `1` every time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `i` to `1` on every iteration of the `for` loop. Move the declaration/initialisation of `i` so that it's before the loop:

```
i = 1
for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
  with open(name) as k:
    content = k.read()
    if '1Chr.'+str(i)+'.' in name:
      book = name.split('.')[0].upper().rstrip()
      x=open('final/'+book+'.SFM', 'a')
      x.write(content)
      i += 1
      x.close()
```